Lubuntu 24.04.1 xrdp - Different Desktop As Lubuntu 22.04.4
Lubuntu 24.04.1 installed fine from scratch (ASUS Z170-A mobo, 1 TB NVMe Samsung 870, 64GB RAM), and also xrdp. However, the resulting desktop screen is different between an xrdp session, and a connected monitor + keyboard + mouse session. The xrdp screen lacks many icon's and has a different panel, all of it different from my Lubuntu 22.04.4 + xrdp. I've been unable to find out why or how I can repair the missing icons problem.
Can anyone please help me ?
Thanks,
Peter

Have you setup your remote login to use the same session as your default login uses? as Lubuntu does include multiple sessions, and your added remote software may have added more.  Lubuntu 24.04 LTS uses a much newer LXQt desktop than 22.04 did (and 22.04 varied depending on if you added backports to your install)

Login to a regular session (not XRDP). What is the output of the command echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP? What is the output of the command echo $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS? Please update the question with these outputs, and then I think I have an answer for you

Also, could you post the outputs of the same commands from the XRDP session?

@guiverc : I noticed that my default login offers me sessions named "Lubuntu", "LXQt Desktop", and "Openbox", and the default, "Lubuntu", is what I would have wanted also via xrdp remote login. Using xrdp however the screen looked more like "LXQt Desktop", with the differences as I noted in my original question. I do not know how to select a different session for xrdp usage.

@Archisman Paningrahi : a regular session shows XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXQt and XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu:/etc/xdg:/etc:/usr/share   And in an XRDP session these environment variables show XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXQt and XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc:/etc/xdg:/usr/share    So it appears that under an XRDP session the first directory, /etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu, is replaced with just /etc with the additional subdirectories. I presume this explains the difference.

However, I should mention that yesterday, I did (the usual) sudo apt-get update + upgrades, and this somehow influenced my icon complaints, in that by now all is working exactly as I wanted them, the same as under Ubuntu 22.04.4. So my problem has gone away ! Thanks for your support though ! Cheers, Peter

This is similar to How to login to the Ubuntu (not GNOME) session on a remote server using xRDP?
If the problem persists, create the hidden file .xsessionrc in your home folder with the following content
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXQt
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu:/etc/xdg:/etc:/usr/share

Logout and Login.
Now it should work in XRDP.
